# Loop invariant of a search algorithm

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, correctness-proof, loop-invariants

I have to come up with a proof of correctness of the following algorithm: GuardedSearch(A; v)

Input: an array A of n numbers and a number v

Output: an index i such that A[i] = v, or NotFound if no such index exists

1. i ← n
2. while i ≥1 and A[i] ≠ v
   a. do i ←i−1
3. if i<1
   a.  then return NotFound
   b.else return i

I know that I have to come up with a loop invariant but I'm struggling to find a correct one. My main problem is with the fact that the while loop has two conditions and i don't know how to solve this. The one that I came up with is the following: At the start of each iteration, if V is not present in A, V is not present in the subarray A[i+1....n].

With this loop invariant, initialization is easy since there is an empty array and the loop invariant thus holds. However when going to the maintenance step I don't know how to continue. I think this is because my loop invariant is incomplete but I have no idea how to get to a correct one. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You can check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585020/loop-invariant-of-linear-search